# Button with a bigger text centering issue

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to do some buttons with image and text, and I already did this work.
But now I´m studying a diferente hypothesis, If I have a text bigger I´m trying to center the text in the button but I´m not having sucess put this right. I´m not having succeess putting my  very big is not good align-center just below the 1st text.
Have you ever had a case like this? How we can solve this?

I have this Html for two buttons:

```
<button class='btn'>
  <img class="big_btn" src="icon1.png" width="40" height="40"/>
      Big button so big <span> very big is not good</span>
</button>
<button class='btn'>
  <img src="icon1.png" width="40" height="40">
      2button big
</button>
```

And I have this css file:

```
.btn {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top:7%;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    line-height: 37px;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 10px;
    font-family: 'bariol_regularregular';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background: #f1f1f1; /* button background  */
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999; /* newsletter button shadow */
    border-radius: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #999;
}

.btn:active {
    top: 1px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.btn img { float: left;}

.btn .big { margin-top:10px;}

.btn:hover { background-color: #f7f7f7;}
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3F9pu/

My image updated:
[image]

Comment: Horizontal center or vertical middle?

Comment: I´m trying to have them vertical, like "Big button so big " above and "very big is not good" just below..but its not easy!

Comment: Posting an image of what you want it to look like would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I pot a image now, my question is how we can proceed in a case like this where we have a larger size of text for the same size button. Because I am not having sucess to align it as I wanted :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your `line-height` attribute. If you set that to be 37px, each new line of text will be separated by 37px. Remove `line-height:37px and the text will wrap around the image.

> <s>line-height: 37px</s>

I also removed your `text-indent` and replaced it with a margin on your floated image to make the text all align properly.

```
.btn img{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

> <s>text-indent: 10px</s>

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3F9pu/6/)

Comment: 2button is not vertically centered.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS background image.

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/3F9pu/5/)

HTML

```
<button class='btn'>Big button so big very big is not good</button>
<button class='btn'>2button big</button>
```

CSS

```css
.btn {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-40-40-3.jpg") #CCC 10px no-repeat;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

[image: screenshot]